# searching for specific entity name in sql xml table columns

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to search for entity names in an sql column?

For example If i have a column that looks like

```
<ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<EntityPropertyOfString>
<Name>User Label 1</Name>
<Value>TX</Value>
 </EntityPropertyOfString>
 <EntityPropertyOfString>
<Name>PD Rate</Name>
<Value>0</Value>
</EntityPropertyOfString>
<EntityPropertyOfString>
<Name>Bonus Day Rate</Name>
<Value>300</Value>
</EntityPropertyOfString>
</ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString>
```

How can I select all the records that have a 'Bonus Day Rate' to get its value??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can be done with xml data types. This would allow querying elements based on path. That's what I would do in Oracle, and it seems sql-server has xml data type support as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT @x.query('(//EntityPropertyOfString[./Name="Bonus Day Rate"]/Value)').value('(.)[1]', 'int')
```

Basically, you find all the nodes named EntityPropertyOfString, and look for the specific one that has a child sub-node of Name with a value of "Bonus Day Rate.  That position is indicated by the square brackets; once you have that position, you query the Value child-node for the first position, and cast it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @T table (ID int identity primary key, XMLCol xml)

declare @xml xml =
'<ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<EntityPropertyOfString>
<Name>User Label 1</Name>
<Value>TX</Value>
 </EntityPropertyOfString>
 <EntityPropertyOfString>
<Name>PD Rate</Name>
<Value>0</Value>
</EntityPropertyOfString>
<EntityPropertyOfString>
<Name>Bonus Day Rate</Name>
<Value>300</Value>
</EntityPropertyOfString>
</ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString>'

insert into @T values (@xml)
insert into @T values (@xml)

select T1.ID,
       T2.N.value('Value[1]', 'int') as Value
from @T as T1
  cross apply T1.XMLCol.nodes('/ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString/EntityPropertyOfString[Name = "Bonus Day Rate"]') as T2(N)
```

Result:

```
ID          Value
----------- -----------
1           300
2           300
```